# How to get body.scrollHeight in script injected of Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Here are the list of my project's files.

```
index.html - main extension file
manifest.json
background.html
background.js
content.js
manifest.json

manifest.json
...
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "all_frames": false,
    "js": [
      "content.js"
    ],
    "matches": [
      "https://www.****.com/vsearch/*"
    ],
    "run_at": "document_end"
  }
]

content.js
...
console.log(document.body.scrollHeight);
```

I need to get scrollHeight of special site in content.js.

But when I load this extension, **sometimes I got scrollHeight of index.html**.

By watching content.js using Chrome Dev Tool, content.js injected correctly in special site.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background/content/popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: Is what you show for your `matches` value within your `content_scripts` in *manifest.json* what you actually are using, or is it changed to hide the site you have specified?